# R: unable to set try and continue for block

Tags: r, exception

I have an R code of the form:

```
for i in 1:no_of_columns_B
{
  for j in 1:no_of_columns_B
   {
     A[i][j]=test(B[i],B[j]) # test is some inbuilt R function
   }
 }
```

Here, in case the test function function fails (raises an error) at some i and j, I need to remove that column j from the B. And corresponding jth row and column from A. Store index j in some array for further reference and continue running the loop.

But since I am new in R, I do not know how to do this. I tried looking at some try catch blocks. But could not figure how to do the task required. So for now, I am doing it manually everytime it fails I delete the indices and run the code.

I want to automate this task as number of columns in B is more than 300.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in 1:no_of_columns_B {
  for j in 1:no_of_columns_B {
     A[i][j] = tryCatch(test(B[i],B[j]), # test is some inbuilt R function
                     error = function(e) {
                                  # do stuff here like remove/ add columns, add to an existing array list
                                  return(NA) # or whatever you want to be stored in the A[i][j] position if an error occurs
                             }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a small issue, I need to store the output of test function in A but it is saving something else as it converts while processing the matrix A into list and throws an error while deleting the indices of A.

Comment: Can you post the error?  I'm not sure I understand...also, I edited the answer to make it clear that you need to return a value inside the error handling.

Comment: The error is: Error in A[,-j] incorrect number of dimensions. I need not save anything in A if error occurs rather remove its row and column.

Comment: Could you post the whole code for what you're trying to do with `A[,-j]`?  It's hard to troubleshoot...